# Is <thead> a required element when used with <tbody>?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I got an unexpected "Error: Invalid table mark-up" if I did not include a `<thead>` element in a `<table>` before `<tbody>`. Including it removes the error, but then I have a heading that I do not need. Is `<thead>` a required element?

I am using JQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: What reported this error? What code triggered it? What does jQuery have to do with this? Are you generating HTML with JavaScript? What version of HTML are you using?

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I guess you're using jQuery-Mobile responsive table. if so, the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 2):

In normal table that we use in html, there is no need to use thead in table.